# How can add product permalink in image a tag woocommerce cart item?

Tags: php, wordpress

Please help to add product permalink at the image a tag, here is my code:

```
<?php
global $woocommerce;  $items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
foreach($items as $item => $values) {
   $_product =  wc_get_product( $values['data']->get_id());

   //product image
   $getProductDetail = wc_get_product( $values['product_id'] );

   echo '<div class="cart-prd-img"><a href="'.esc_url( get_permalink( $product->id ) ).'">'.$getProductDetail->get_image().'</div>'; // accepts 2 arguments ( size, attr )
   echo '<div class="cart-prd-name">'.$_product->get_title().'</div>';  
    '<br> Quantity: '.$values['quantity'].'<br>';

   $price = get_post_meta($values['product_id'] , '_price', true);
        echo "  Price: ".$price."<br>";
} ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach($items as $item => $values) {
   $_product =  wc_get_product( $values['data']->get_id());

   //product image
   $getProductDetail = wc_get_product( $values['product_id'] );

   //get the id of product
   $product_id = $values['product_id'];

   //$product->id is null. to get the product link you have need to use valid product id - get_permalink( $product_id ) 

   echo '<div class="cart-prd-img"><a href="'.esc_url( get_permalink( $product_id ) ).'">'.$getProductDetail->get_image().'</div>'; // accepts 2 arguments ( size, attr )
   echo '<div class="cart-prd-name">'.$_product->get_title().'</div>';  
    '<br> Quantity: '.$values['quantity'].'<br>';

   $price = get_post_meta($values['product_id'] , '_price', true);
        echo "  Price: ".$price."<br>";
} ?>
```